# Is there any reason to prefer Prototype to JQuery?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I don't mean for this to be inflammatory, so please don't take it that way. As someone who has used Prototype a lot and JQuery a little, they both seem very similar, but JQuery (at least initially) looks cleaner and more well thought-out. At this point I am wondering, other than tight integration out of the box with frameworks like Rails or Seaside, what advantages are there to using Prototype over JQuery?

Comment: Take a look at <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176324/why-does-everyone-like-jquery-more-than-prototype-script-aclo-us-or-mootools-or-w">this question</a>.

Comment: You probably might want to tag this 'subjectiv'. (And that might be the answer to your question, really.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No. JQuery requires fewer lines of code and is more widely accepted. It has pretty much become the industry standard toolkit. Some vendors like Microsoft, are even shipping it with their latest products. Additionally, JQuery has over a thousand free plugins available, and the list is growing daily. They provide an incredibly amount of functionality that would take forever to develop on your own. No other toolkit even comes close. It also has a very very active and helpful user community. There is lots of documentation on the .NET for JQuery.

Answer (score 4):

[Defining classes and inheritance](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance) is built-in the framework.

Comment: I think is one of the most profound features of Prototype. In jQuery you'd create plug-ins and do manual JS prototypal inheritance

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. JQuery is easier to implement, has more plugins and is in general better than any other similar stuff out there (for now).