# Does scriptaculous come with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I read that prototype does but didn't know if that means scriptaculous does.  I looked at the javascript folder and it had prototype, dragdrop, controls, effects, and application.  Is that all scriptaculous?  Do I just add a link to it in my layout to use it?

Also, The scriptaculous website said all sorts of "big names" use it, but I've only use jquery.  Is Scriptaculous okay compared to Jquery?  Is it about to "die" or anything that would make it better for me to install jquery in the javascript folder of RoR?  I have used jquery but am no expert and don't mind switching to the other if it's not a dead language.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that all scriptaculous? Do I just add a link to it in my layout to use it?

Basically, yes. It is a JavaScript library that is split into those components.

You can specify which components to load by specifying them in the central `scriptaculous.js` call:

```
<script src="scriptaculous.js?load=effects,dragdrop" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

As to

> Is it about to "die" or anything that would make it better for me to install jquery in the javascript folder of RoR?

There are several questions about this on SO, best refer to them. I'd say the bias is going heavily towards jQuery, for several good reasons (I'm a former Prototype / Scriptaculous user myself). I don't know what dependencies RoR has with Prototype, though, so I can't say how easy it is to use jQuery instead in whatever you are planning to do.

Related:

- [Why does everyone like jQuery more than prototype/script.aculo.us or MooTools or whatever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176324/why-does-everyone-like-jquery-more-than-prototype-script-aculo-us-or-mootools-or)
- [shall I move from prototype to jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561402/shall-i-move-from-prototype-to-jquery)
- [Prototype VS jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644556/prototype-vs-jquery)